# Extract Data From Plain HTML

Tags: html, regex, extract

I have a snippet of html containing the first part of a post code and the region it is in. An example of two rows:

```
<tr height="17">
  <td class="xl66" height="17">Channel Islands</td>
  <td class="xl66">GY - (Guernsey)</td>
</tr>
<tr height="17">
  <td class="xl66" height="17">Channel Islands</td>
  <td class="xl66">JE - (Jersey)</td>
</tr>
```

How/what can I use to extract the region and the part of the postcode minus the name of the location.

From the example data, I would like to retrieve `('Channel Islands', 'GY'), ('Channel Islands', 'JE')` so I can enter them into a database.

Comment: What operating system are you using?Linux or windows?

Comment: Which language should be used?

Comment: are you using PHP for the backend? and MySQL for the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**USING GAWK**

Using gawk scripting language can prove worthwhile

create a file name `gawkscript` and add the following:

```
#Test to see if the line matches the region, if it does, use regex to get your region
$0~/<td class="xl66" height="17">Channel Islands<\/td>/{printf gensub(/ *<td.*>(.+)<\/td>/,"\\1,",$0)};

#Test to see if the line matches the cose, if it does, use regex to get your code
$0~/<td class="xl66">(.+)<\/td>/{print gensub(/ *<td.*>(.+) *- \(.+\)<\/td>/,"\\1",$0)}
```

using your shell you can run the script

```
gawk -f gawkscript   my_html_file
```

Since this is html codes we are dealing with, I would use a powerful html webscraping module in python call `BeautifulSoup`

**USING PYTHON**
Assuming you know some python

```
import re #import regex
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #import beautifulsoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(
#add your html string
    """<tr height="17">
  <td class="xl66" height="17">Channel Islands</td>
  <td class="xl66">GY - (Guernsey)</td>
</tr>

<tr height="17">
  <td class="xl66" height="17">Channel Islands</td>
  <td class="xl66">JE - (Jersey)</td>
</tr>""")
#find all tr tags in your html string 
find_all_tr=soup.find_all("tr")  
for i in find_all_tr: #loop through all tr tags
        all_td=BeautifulSoup(str(i)).find_all("td") #find all td tags
        for j in all_td:
#check to see if your td tages matches 'td class="xl66" height="17"' and print
            if re.search('<td class="xl66" height="17"',str(j)): 
                print(j.text.strip(),end=" ")
#check to see if your td tag matches ONLY <td class="xl66" and use regex to obtain your country code
            elif re.search('<td class="xl66">',str(j)):
                print(","+re.sub(".*-","",j.text.strip()))
```

**NOTE: I use strip() function here because html to eliminate the unwanted newline characters in html codes when extracting information**

Comment: this is a python3x script not 2x

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex

```
/<td.*?>(.*?)<\/td.*?>\s+<td.*?>(.*?)\s-.*?<\/td>/gi
```

**[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/tB4mB1/3)**

Comment: Why did you use `<\/td.*?>`? Closing nodes cannot have attributes. And a hint: never use `.*` when you want to match the inside of the node.

Comment: Regex is too unsafe to parse out values from HTML code, and you made it even more unsafe with lazy dot matching. Anyway, if anyone thinks it is of value, let'em upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

I can make your work with the help of javascript as i have less knowledge in regex.

Here the JS code :

```
var array = [];
var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
var rowLength = table.rows.length;
for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {
  var collect = [];
  var col = table.rows.item(i).cells;
  var colLength = col.length;
  for (var j = 0; j < colLength; j++) {
    var value = col.item(j).innerHTML;
    collect.push(value);
  }
  array.push(collect);
}
```

Here is the working link

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/8e67Il0u5dmr6NZX3FWJ?p=preview
```

Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing server-side specifics like languages (PHP/ASP) and  database (MySQL/NoSQL), I cannot show you how to handle the code in the back-end.

That being said, the code below shows you how to handle and prepare the data client-side and make an asynchronous (POST) request via JavaScript to your server.

---

#### Related Information:

Here is a well documented guide for the -- [**FormData( )** object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)

Here is a well documented guide for the -- [**XMLHttpRequest( )** object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

---

Screenshot:

[image]

---

//HTML (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="submitTable();">Click Me</button>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Region</th>
            <th>Postcode</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="data-row">
            <td>Channel Islands</td>
            <td>GY - (Guernsey)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="data-row">
            <td>Channel Islands</td>
            <td>JE - (Jersey)</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

//JS (index.js)

```
function submitTable(){
    //OBJECT INITIALIZATION
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ 
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();  // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari                     
    }
    else{ 
        var request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // IE 6 and older
    }
    var formData = new FormData();
    
    //LOOP THROUGH DATA and APPEND to FormData(object)
    var dataRows = document.getElementsByClassName("data-row");
    for(var i=0; i < dataRows.length; i++){
        var data = dataRows[i].children;
        for(var x=0; x < data.length; x++){
            if(x === 1){
                var postcode = data[x].innerHTML.substr(0, 2);
                formData.append("postcode", data[x].innerHTML);
            }
            else{
                formData.append("region", data[x].innerHTML);
            }
        }
    }
    //OPEN
    request.open("POST", "/path/to/post/the/data");
    //SEND
    request.send(formData);
    //RESPONSE
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(request.readyState == 4){
            console.log(request.response);
        }
    }
}
```

//CSS (index.css)

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```